# How to send json data from url to database and update it

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hy,

I just cant figure it out how to get this to work.

How do I post the home>name, home>score to the database (the same for away) and send the status, rounds and datetime to the database.
But if there is a change in the json url than update the database and if there is a new match insert it.

this all needs to be done automatically.

```
[
   {
  "url":"http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/tournaments/10423-starladder-cis-minor-championship-cologne-2016/2865-playoffs/10426-playoffs/matches/113497-worst-players-vs-team-empire",
  "home":{
     "name":"Worst Players",
     "url":"/counterstrike/teams/15191-worst-players",
     "country":"Russian Federation",
     "rank":57,
     "score":1
  },
  "away":{
     "name":"Team Empire.",
     "url":"/counterstrike/teams/14464-team-empire",
     "country":"Russian Federation",
     "rank":40,
     "score":2
  },
  "status":"Complete",
  "type":"counterstrike",
  "rounds":"Best of 3",
  "valueBet":true,
  "datetime":1462024800
   },
   {
  "url":"http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/tournaments/10296-esports-championship-series-season-1/2810-online-phase/10298-north-american-league/matches/111367-team-liquid-cs-vs-counter-logic-gaming-cs",
  "home":{
     "name":"Team Liquid.CS",
     "url":"/counterstrike/teams/10561-team-liquid-cs",
     "country":"United States",
     "rank":10
  },
  "away":{
     "name":"Counter Logic Gaming.CS",
     "url":"/counterstrike/teams/10569-counter-logic-gaming-cs",
     "country":"United States",
     "rank":39
  },
  "status":"Upcoming",
  "type":"counterstrike",
  "rounds":"Best of 3",
  "valueBet":true,
  "datetime":1462068000
   }
]
```

I have tried this code

```
<?php

include("../../check.php"); 

$urljson = "http://localhost:5000/matches";
$json = file_get_contents($urljson);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$home = $data[0]['home'];
$away = $data[0]['away'];
$status = $data[0]['status'];
$type = $data[0]['rounds'];
$timestamp = $data[0]['datetime'];


foreach($data as $array) {
    echo $home['name'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $home['score'];
echo '<br>';
echo $away['name'];
echo '<br>';
echo $away['score'];
echo '<br>';
echo $status;
echo '<br>';
echo $type;
echo '<br>';
echo $timestamp;
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
}


?>
```

but this is what the webpage gave me (it showed mutiple times the same result)

> ANOX
>
> Notice: Undefined index: score in C:\xampp\htdocs\main\dashboard\backend\info.php on line 18
>
> Worst Players
>
> Notice: Undefined index: score in C:\xampp\htdocs\main\dashboard\backend\info.php on line 22
>
> Upcoming
>
> Best of 3
>
> 1462100400

I hope someone can help me with this beceause I am stuck for like 4 days now.

Comment: I've tested the code you have provided and it is working fine for me (although your loop doesn't work as it should). Are you sure you are getting the JSON you think you are?

Comment: Well I host it on my pc so I am getting it from the perfect link "http://localhost:5000/matches" and all the data is also showing there.

Answer (score 0):

You get the same data all the time cause you are using the wrong variables inside the loop. Use the $array variable in your case:

```
foreach($data as $array) {
    echo $array['name'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $array['score'];
    echo '<br>';
    ... etc.
}
```

Maybe it would be good to call the variable $row or $match instead of $array for better readability.

You get the "Notice: Undefined..." because there are some JSON nodes where there is no score. Check for score before using it with

```
if (isset($array['score'])) {
    // use it inside if:
    echo $array['score']
}
```

Here the corrected code:

```
<?php

include("../../check.php"); 

$urljson = "http://localhost:5000/matches";
$json = file_get_contents($urljson);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach($data as $match) {
    echo $match['home']['name'];
    echo '<br>';
    if (isset($match['home']['score'])) {
        echo $match['home']['score'];
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo $match['away']['name'];
    echo '<br>';
    if (isset($match['away']['score'])) {
        echo $match['away']['score'];
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo $match['status'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $match['rounds'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $match['datetime'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, can you also help me how to detect changes in the json url and then update it in the database?

Comment: you would need to load the data from the database and then compare it in some way. First find some identifying part of the data that is unique and use that to compare the data from the database to the json. Then insert, update and maybe delete the data in the database.

Comment: This also depends on the database used: you could make a unique key and in case of mysql use the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax. Other databases like e.g. keyvalue stores simply insert if the key doesnt exist. In this case simply insert all the data and you will update it if it already existed.